# subscribing to a property change in a NavigationService page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I really am stuck with this, mainly because I don't quite get event handling.

I have a ProcessManager.XAML page called from the MainPage.XAML. If I make a change to a list in the ProcessManager.XAML, such as adding a procedure, I need the MainPage.XAML to know it has happened. Could anyone explain to me how I could do this, at the moment I have a bool value that changes to true when a change to the list happens but I have no idea how to let the MainPage.XAML know it has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it in the end. A simple implementation of an event, which I have never done before, solved it. 
I used the following as a template: 
[Simple event handler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a variable visible from both pages.

The easiest way to accomplish that is to create a "global" *bool HasChanged* in App.xaml.cs

```
public bool HasChanged = false;
```

Then you can access it from any place in your app like this:

```
(Application.Current as App).HasChanged = true;
```

of

```
if ((Application.Current as App).HasChanged)
    MessageBox.Show("CHANGE CHANGE");
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought of that but didn't try it as it still needs an event to check that it has been changed. I felt that a subscription would be a better way to go. Thanks any way.

Comment: You can also extend this approach by adding an event to App.xaml.cs that code on your other pages can subscribe to. The event gets fired by the Setter for `HasChanged`.